# Animation applies to all imageviews in a grid?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a GridView of images. The images are displayed as they are downloaded, and I wanted to make them have a fade-in effect as the image is populated with the bitmap.
I've added code to do this, but the animation applies to all of the images, not just the one being loaded at the time. This means that all the images fade in a tiny amount then vanish as the next bitmap is set and the animation restarts.

How can I get the animation to only apply to the image being loaded at the time?

Fade-in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
android:duration="2500" android:repeatCount="0"/>
</set>
```

And here is the code for loading the images in the ImageAdapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {

            BorderedImageView imageView;
            imageView = new BorderedImageView(mContext, mPhotoId, position);
            Animation myFadeInAnimation =    AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.mContext , R.anim.fadein);

            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mSize, mSize));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(3,3,3,3);
            } else {
                imageView = (BorderedImageView) convertView;
            }

            Bitmap b = photoCollection.GetThumbnail(position);
            imageView.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
            return imageView;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT** OK actually it's obvious why this happens - I'm calling notifydatasetchanged() each time a thumbnail is downloaded, so the above code will get run for all images each time one downloads.
Still not sure how to fix it though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've fixed this now.

I moved the animation into my own ImageView class, and added a method to start the animation.
This is triggered by a flag on my collection of photos that is set when the thumbnail download is complete.